# NSInvalidArgumentException when trying to use "Symbol" from react-native-svg library

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-native

I'm trying to use the `react-native-svg` library particularly with the `Symbol` element as follows. I used the example code here:

```
    <Svg
    height="150"
    width="110"
>
    <Symbol id="symbol" viewbox="0 0 150 110" width="100" height="50">
        <Circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" strokeWidth="8" stroke="red" fill="red"/>
        <Circle cx="90" cy="60" r="40" strokeWidth="8" stroke="green" fill="white"/>
    </Symbol>

    <Use
        href="#symbol"
        x="0"
        y="0"
    />
```

When I run this code, I get the following error in the logs and the app crashes:
`<Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'`

When I don't use the `Symbol` object everything works fine. Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to fix this by copying and pasting the example on this page: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol

You need the `width` and `height` elements on the `Use` tag as follows:

```
<Svg height="150" width="110">
            <Symbol id="symbol" viewbox="0 0 150 110" width="100" height="50">
                <Circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" strokeWidth="8" stroke="red" fill="red"/>
                <Circle cx="90" cy="60" r="40" strokeWidth="8" stroke="green" fill="white"/>
            </Symbol>

            <Use href="#symbol" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50"/>
        </Svg>
```

I definitely thought I tried that before, so it may have also been me running the following clear cache and re-compiling commands as well:
`rm -rf node_modules && npm install` and `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Either way, problem fixed!